# Why is Jade not using the correct local variable?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to fetch the users from MongoDB via Mongoose and send them to the view. For some reason, when I try to iterate through the `users` array in my Jade template, I get the `users` variable from my app.js instead of the `users` array I'm passing to the view. How can that be in scope?

Also, when I output the `locals` variable in the view I see the correct value for `users`. Strange.

**// app.js**

```
var users = new UsersController();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('home', { users: users });
  });
});
```

**// home.jade**

```
div.users
  each user in users
    p!= user
```

Comment: Quick test on my machine with latest express and jade and it worked as expected. `users` was a list of users passed via `render` 2nd parameter. I just did: `var users = [{name: "aaron"}, {name: "jane"}];

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', { users : users});
});`

Comment: Yeah, it's strange. I just tried the exact same setup, this time using EJS, it worked as expected. For some reason Jade is not accessing the `users` that is passed to the view and instead accessing the `users` from app.js

Comment: Are there any other differences? It worked with Jade for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var users = new UsersController();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.locals.users = users;
    res.render('home');
  });
});

div.users
  each user in #{users]
    p!= user
```